# how to sort array with any number of elements in java?

Tags: java, sorting

how to sort an array with any number of elements in java?

I create an array that allows the user to choose the number of elements but I don't know how to sort it.

this is the array code

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the size of the array: ");
            int r = input.nextInt();
            int[] list = new int[r];
            init(list);
```

Comment: Not trying to be rude but you get an answer to this by literally googling your exact question title. What kept you from doing so?

Comment: no they create array and sort it in seem method, sorry

Comment: Sorry, this is just not true. This is such a well covered and basic topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
Arrays.sort(list);
```

Comment: can I try it in another method?

Comment: @TalalAlosaimi have you tried it?

Comment: can i ask u what is mean (list) ?

Comment: @TalalAlosaimi `list` is a variable you use in your code. You pass it to the function `Arrays.sort` as a parameter.